# JavaScript export array from one file to another to be used. Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays

Perhaps you can help.
I have a file the is listing the DIR then pushing it to an array. I'm then trying to export it and use it in another file. But its not working....

**File 1.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
let filename = [];
module.exports = function(){


try {
    let subfolder = './DIR/';
    fs.readdir(subfolder, async (err, files) => {
        for (const file of files) {
            filename.push(file);
        }

    });
}
catch (e) {}
};
```

**File 2.js**

```
let instance = require('../../File 2');
console.log(instance);
```

However when I run this I get an empty array back. however I can console.log within the file 1.js for the array and it shows correctly. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Compare the output of `process.env.PWD` where it is and is not working. Probably a path issue.

Comment: You are not exporting the filename variable, File2.js should print the function and not an empty array

Answer (score 0):

1. You're exporting a function, not an array.
2. The array will be filled asynchronously. When you `console.log` in `File 2.js`, the array will still be empty.

Comment: Ok, How do you export the array.

Comment: You can't really, because you're building the array asynchronously.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to build the array not asynchronously so that it can be exported

Comment: Node.js has a `readdirSync` function that does that. Generally the `Sync` functions are not recommended though, but it's fine if you only do it once when you 'start' your application.

Comment: Perfect I changed File 1.js to be:
let files = fs.readdirSync(subfolder);

And it worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Result was changing **File 1.js** to be the following:

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = 
{
    getRArray: function ()
    {
        let filename = [];
        try
        {
            let subfolder = './DIR/';
            let files = fs.readdirSync(subfolder);

            for (let file of files)
            {
                filename.push(file);
            }
        }
        catch (e)
        {
        }
        return filename;
    }
};
```

with **File 2.js**

```
let instance = require('../../DIR');
console.log(instance.getRArray());
```